# is it possible to list documentation via yum like RPM does

Tags: yum, rpm

rpm has the function `rpm -qd somepackage`  which will list all documentation files associated with the given package.

does `yum` have such a feature? I am unable to find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is “no”. `yum` was written to complement the `rpm` command and not to replicate its features.

The `rpm` command works well for getting information on installed packages or downloaded packages. To obtain a file listing of a (non-downloaded) package from a repository, use the `repoquery` utility (provided by the `yum-utils` package).

```
yum install yum-utils
repoquery --list package_name
```

In most cases the documentation files are stored in `/usr/share/doc/` so the file listing could be filtered using `grep`, e.g,

```
repoquery --list tree | grep doc
```

See: [Displaying Package Information](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Displaying_Package_Information.html)